# node-gyp build library dependencies

Tags: node.js, boost, node-gyp, libtorrent, gyp

I want to find a way to simplify the installation of the Node.js "[libtorrent](https://npmjs.org/package/libtorrent)" module.

My goal is to be able to provide pre-compiled .node files for each architectures, as this is done in the [fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) module for example.

This way, the users can install the module without the need to install dependencies, compile, etc.

My question is : if I want to do that, do I need to include all dependencies (libtorrent and some Boost libaries) inside the project and build them with node-gyp too ? Or if I build the module on my system with these dependencies installed, they will be included in the final .node file ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Boost` and `Node` are C++ programs their (e.g. function) names get mangled at compile time. When they will not be compiled together, they should theoretically not be able to know of one another. `.node` files are some binary format and `gyp` has no functionality, that I know of, that can associate binary symbols.

So I am pretty sure you need to compile them at dev time. I think this would also support your general idea of providing pre-compiled stuff, though tremendously increasing file-size of course.